# Table of name ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column called Mode having different values (Air, Surface etc.)
In the below formula I am using Named Range with the same name as Mode (Air, Air_r, Air_c, Surface, Surface_c,etc.).

```
=IF([@Mode]="AIR",CONCATENATE(LEFT(RIGHT(CELL("address",INDEX(AIR,MATCH(IF([@[Charged Weight]]>0.5,0.51,[@[Charged Weight]]),air_r,1),MATCH([@Zone],air_c,0),1)),3),1),RIGHT(CELL("address",INDEX(AIR,MATCH(IF([@[Charged Weight]]>0.5,0.51,[@[Charged Weight]]),air_r,0),MATCH([@Zone],air_c,0),1)),1)),0)
```

How can the Index Array & rows & columns be changed dynamically with reference to value in Mode cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `INDIRECT` is what you're looking for, along the lines of:

```
INDEX(indirect([@Mode]),MATCH(MIN([@[Charged Weight]],0.51)),indirect([@Mode]&"_r"),1)
```

Comment: yes this is what i was looking for, but its giving a reference error this may be because the mode is coming from a different sheet

Comment: Thanks for the MIN update. Any way to change the concatenate thing in the formula that i posted.

Comment: I have to confess, I don't entirely understand what the concatenate is achieving - all those `LEFT`s and `RIGHT`s make it hard for me to keep it all straight in my head.

Comment: I wanted the cell address, not the workbook name with it, so from the left n rights, i slice away the rest of the part except the last cell location like E3, F6, etc